# Convert resquest.content into Panda Dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm requesting to login and download data from a server like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO
import json

url = "http://192.168.18.18/vicidial/call_report_export.php"

querystring = {"DB":"",
           "run_export":"1",
           "ivr_export":"",
           "query_date":"2019-10-22",
           "end_date":"2019-10-22",
           "date_field":"call_date",
           "header_row":"YES",
           "rec_fields":"NONE",
           "call_notes":"NO",
           "export_fields":"STANDARD",
           "campaign[]":["EdsnSTF","SuperED"],
           "SUBMIT":"SUBMIT",
           "campaign%5B%5D":["EdsnSTF","SuperED"]}

headers = {'Authorization': "Basic ZWs5NjAxNDoxMjUw",
           'Accept': "*/*",
           'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
           'Host': "192.168.18.18",
           'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
           'Connection': "keep-alive",
           'cache-control': "no-cache"
           }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.content)
```

The content of the response is:

```
b'call_date\tphone_number_dialed\tstatus\tuser\tfull_name\tcampaign_id\tvendor_lead_code\tsource_id\tlist_id\tgmt_offset_now\tphone_code\tphone_number\ttitle\tfirst_name\tmiddle_initial\tlast_name\taddress1\taddress2\taddress3\tcity\tstate\tprovince\tpostal_code\tcountry_code\tgender\tdate_of_birth\talt_phone\temail\tsecurity_phrase\tcomments\tlength_in_sec\tuser_group\talt_dial\trank\towner\tlead_id\tlist_name\tlist_description\tstatus_name\r\n
```

I can't convert it into a data frame in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That response only looks like the header row of the response. and is missing a `'` at the end.

It is a `bytes`, so you'll need to convert it to a string `content.decode(<encoding>)` . The encoding is probably UTF8, but can be ASCII, or something else, depending on the server.

Then with `pandas.read_csv`:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(content.decode("utf8")), sep="\t")
```

you get a DataFrame

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it resolved my problem. anyway if I change the date of the query string to get data from another data I get this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 171007: invalid continuation byte

Comment: I did like this: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.content.decode("utf8" , errors="ignore")), sep="\t") and there is not anymore error, thank you

Comment: Ignoring encoding errors is not the way to handle this. Either utf8 is wrong, and then you are misinterpreting date, or the server is sending corrupt data. Ignoring will lead to hard to track bugs and anomalies